# Change width of div when focused on a different form

Tags: css

I'm having trouble getting this to work

```
#searchform:hover, #s:focus #searchform {width: 195px;}
```

Shouldn't that tell #searchform to have a 195px width when #s is focused? Am I missing something here?

The #searchform is a parent of #s would this be the reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The #searchform is a parent of #s would this be the reason why?

Yes, you can't select a parent based on the state of its children with CSS only.